# How can I load a yaml rosparam file for a nodelet?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, yaml, nodelet, rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Usually, when writing a launch file and wanting to set many `rosparam`s at once, one would place them in a YAML file which is then loaded for the node like this:

```
   <node
        name="$(arg node_name)"
        pkg="pylon_camera"
        type="pylon_camera_node"
        output="screen"
        respawn="$(arg respawn)"
        launch-prefix="$(arg launch_prefix)" >
        <param name="camera_frame" value="$(arg node_name)" type="string" />
        <rosparam command="load" file="$(arg config_file)" />
    </node>
```

Now, the same does not seem to work in a nodelet.

```
<node if="$(arg start_pylon_driver)"
    pkg="nodelet"
    type="nodelet"
    name="PylonNodelet"
    args="load pylon_camera/PylonNodelet $(arg manager_name)"
    output="screen"
    respawn="false">
      <param name="camera_frame" value="pylon_camera" type="string" />
      <rosparam command="load" file="$(arg config_file)" />
</node>
```

The nodelet loads and runs, but the parameters are all default values, not the ones set in the `config.yaml`.
How can this be accomplished?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268856/how-can-i-load-a-yaml-rosparam-file-for-a-nodelet?/) by [themightyoarfish](https://answers.ros.org/users/31133/themightyoarfish/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-08-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-08-15**:
What pylon_camera is this?  https://github.com/magazino/pylon_camera doesn't support nodelets.

**Comment by [themightyoarfish](https://answers.ros.org/users/31133/themightyoarfish/) on 2017-08-15**:
What do you mean it doesn't support nodelets? I simply made the required additions to the codebase, it's basically as simple as writing a nodelet subclass which does what `main.cpp` does otherwise. The nodelet is working alright, it just doesn't respect the config params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's possible the param getting is being done wrong within the nodelet, and it is loading params from the manager namespace rather than the nodelet.

The nodelet needs to be using

```
getPrivateNodeHandle().getParam("camera_frame", camera_frame_)
```

rather than the following which is what a non-nodelet node would usually do:

```
ros::NodeHandle nh("~");
nh.getParam("camera_frame", camera_frame_);
```

Also try `rosparam list` to see if the parameters in the yaml files are correctly being loaded.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [themightyoarfish](https://answers.ros.org/users/31133/themightyoarfish/) on 2017-08-15**:
These two code snippets look as if they were doing the same thing. isn't `"~"` a private namespace?

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-08-15**:
The plugins get loaded and run inside the nodelet manager, which has a different private namespace from the node that asks the manager to launch a specific nodelet.  getPrivateNodeHandle() gets you the namespace of the nodelet launcher.